# OnPress button with ViewOverflow not working on android

Tags: react-native, onpress

I have a custom component based on TouchableOpacity,
I followed this tutorial

https://itnext.io/react-native-tab-bar-is-customizable-c3c37dcf711f

It used overflow View, but unfortunatly onPress() is not working with an overflow View in react native, someone found a workaround ?

Here my button

```
<AnimatedViewOverflow style={{
     position: 'absolute',
     width: SIZE / 2,
     height: SIZE / 2,
    ...style
}}>
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => onPress && onPress()}
    style={{
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: SIZE / 2,
        height: SIZE / 2,
        borderRadius: SIZE / 4,
        backgroundColor: '#48A2F8'
    }}
    >
      <Icon name={icon} size={16} color="#F8F8F8"/>
   </TouchableOpacity>
</AnimatedViewOverflow>
```

Here when I do my onPress, but console.log is never written

```
 <SubAddButton
                style={{transform: transform(firstX, firstY, firstZ)}}
                icon="rocket"
                onPress={() => console.log('OK1')}
   />
```

Source are available here:
https://github.com/alex-melnyk/Tabber/tree/overflow_fixed

Comment: Does it work in iOS?

Comment: @MateoGuzmán yes !

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: no, I made a post on react-native github, and they told me it's actually not supported for the moment with android...